# Continuously update the time in android

Tags: android

I need the current time twice in same activity (OnCreate() and button press). 
I'm getting the current time using a API. I do a API communication in onCreate() and then I do another communication in button press. But I don't want to do that. I want to run the time from the data I got in onCreate() API communication. (For ex: If user opens the activity at 5.00 am and user press the button at 5:10 am then the timer should run for 10 minutes)

Is there a way to run a timer using the data got first from API call without continuously communicating with the API. 
I'm using following url to get the data, 
https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyd5AcbAnWi2Yn0xhFRbyzS4qMq1VucMVgVvhul5XqS9HkAyJY/exec?tz=Asia/Colombo

I was looking at this tutorial to implement my code,
http://android-er.blogspot.com/2013/12/example-of-using-timer-and-timertask-on.html

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [elapsedRealtime](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html#elapsedRealtime%28%29); Store the value when you get the time from the API in `onCreate` and use it again when you want to know the time difference since the first call.